# How to filter out a field in an array field inside of an object?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to filter by id an array field inside an object.

this is what I tried to do:

```
 editPhases(id) {

 var formules = this.allFormules

  for (let i = 0; i < formules.length; i++) {
  for (let i = 0; i < formules[i].phases.length; i++) {
  if(formules[i].phases[i]._id == id) {
    console.log("ok")
   }

   }

 }
```

formules is an array of objects , each object has an array field called phases.
I would like to to do a for loop over this field and find where phases._id == id.

Thanks !

Comment: You're trying to declare two variables called `i`. Try calling the second variable `j`.

Comment: Is `phases` another array of objects inside your `formules` array of objects? It would be helpful if you could provide a sample of how your `formules` look. Also if an `_id` is matched, do you want to filter out the `phase` or the `formule`?

Comment: phases ia another array of objects inside formules yeah , and I would like to filter out the phase @nash11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `j` variable to your inner loop and use it to call `phares` items.

```js
function editPhases(id) {

  const formules = this.allFormules;
  const results = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < formules.length; i++) {
    for (const j = 0; j < formules[j].phases.length; i++) {
      if (formules[i].phases[j]._id === id) {
        results.push(formules[i].phases[j]);
      }
    }
  }
  return results;
}
```

Comment: Thanks m8 it worked , I just need to filter out the phase that matches the id , may you help me ?

Comment: Not sure I understand what the problem is now. This will print "ok" in console every time ids match. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to filter out all the phases every time when the ids match so I could have an array of all those phases

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map` and `filter` together to achieve your result.

Here is a working example.

```js
const allFormules = [{
  phases: [
    {_id: 1},
    {_id: 2}
  ]
}, {
  phases: [
    {_id: 1},
    {_id: 2},
    {_id: 3}
  ]
}];

function editPhases(id) {

  const formules = allFormules;

  formules.map(formule => 
    formule.phases = formule.phases.filter(phases => phases._id == id)
  );
  
  return formules;
}

console.log(editPhases(1));
```

Comment: hey m8 , I tried to do as you said :  var detail = formules.forEach(formule => {
      formule.phases.filter(phase => phase._id === id);
  }); , but detail remains undefined (and I double checked if I have a phase with this id in my data base and there is)

Comment: @BarLevin - I have added a working example to my answer.